# How would I go about making buttons flash?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I'm making a application for playing Connect4. I wanted to indicate the players turn more clearly by having the clickable buttons flash the color of the players turn. I was wondering how I would go about doing that. Sorry if this has been answered before, if so can you please link me to the post.

```
bgwMain = new BackgroundWorker();
bgwMain.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

int Red;
int Green;
int Blue;

bgwMain.DoWork += ;

while (!mre.WaitOne())
{
    for (int i = 0; i != 255; i++)
    {
        Red = i;
        Green = i;

        for (int z = 42; z <= btnLongArray.Length - 1; z++)
        {
            btnLongArray[z].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(Red, Green, 0);
        }

        if (i == 255)
        {
            for (int x = 255; x != 0; x--)
            {
                Red = x;
                Green = x;

                for (int z = 42; z <= btnLongArray.Length - 1; z++)
                {
                    btnLongArray[z].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(Red, Green, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a good grasp of event driven programming and I'm pretty sure this would require some sort of event checker or background worker. I'm not sure how to go about making this work. My current error is on the while loop "!mre.waitone" and "bgwMain.DoWork += ;."Not to sure what I was trying to do with this as it's been a while since I last opened this project. I believe I was trying to call a Manual Reset Event Class, either way, I'm not to sure. Please let me know how I should go about making this happen, thanks in advance!

Comment: Button flash? Use `Timer`. You can enable/disable timer to start/stop flashing.

Comment: What app is it? Perhaps Win Forms? Or WPF, UWP etc.

Comment: @DanielDušek This is using Window Forms

Comment: Have you seen e.g. [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VbkYxVzFlQk) example? It seems to be implemented many times alread, just google for it.

Comment: Using a timer worked thank you @Sinatr

Answer (score 0):

```
// Keeps track of the number of blinks
private int m_nBlinkCount = 0;

// ...

// tmrTimer is a component added to the form.
tmrTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTimerTick);

m_nBlinkCount = 0;
tmrTimer.Interval = 1000; // 1 second interval
tmrTimer.Start();

// In Tick event, keep changing the background color of your button

private void OnTimerTick ( Object sender, EventArgs eventargs)
{
    if (btnLongArray.BackColor == Color.Red)
        btnLongArray.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    else
        btnLongArray.BackColor = Color.Red;

    m_nBlinkCount++;

    if ( m_nBlinkCount >= 10 )
        tmrTimer.Stop ();
}
```